# Select query from json format data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

**I just want a select query where it can Select all user uid who have born after 1986 Year.**

I tried this query but it only selects the matching number `LIKE` search.

```
SELECT uid FROM {profile_values} WHERE  value LIKE  '%1986%'
```

Here is the SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile_values` (
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`fid`),
  KEY `fid` (`fid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `profile_values` (`fid`, `uid`, `value`) VALUES
(5, 1, 'a:3:{s:3:"day";s:2:"27";s:5:"month";s:1:"6";s:4:"year";s:4:"1986";}'),
(5, 3, 'a:3:{s:3:"day";s:2:"15";s:5:"month";s:1:"9";s:4:"year";s:4:"1910";}'),
(5, 4, 'a:3:{s:3:"day";s:2:"26";s:5:"month";s:1:"6";s:4:"year";s:4:"1986";}'),
(5, 5, 'a:3:{s:5:"month";s:1:"4";s:3:"day";s:2:"26";s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";}'),
(5, 6, 'a:3:{s:3:"day";s:2:"26";s:5:"month";s:1:"4";s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";}'),
(5, 7, 'a:3:{s:5:"month";s:1:"4";s:3:"day";s:2:"26";s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";}'),
(5, 8, 'a:3:{s:3:"day";s:2:"26";s:5:"month";s:1:"4";s:4:"year";s:4:"1987";}'),
(5, 17, 'N;'),
(5, 18, 'N;'),
```

Comment: my goodness, why can you just create the necessary columns for that instead of inserting a serialized array

Comment: either decode the string prior to storage (and store in a normalized way), or do the search in php (with javascript?)

Comment: first thing is to create more structured database, because this is not recommended

Comment: your query is not correct. It should be `value >= '1986'`

Comment: why cant you just save the date as  `DATE` column

Comment: Its default drupal way of storing date data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try REGEXP. The REGEXP matching condition is similar to the LIKE but LIKE only performs simple pattern matching using the wildcards "%" and "_", REGEXP performs complex regular expression pattern matching allowing it to match a much greater range of string patterns than LIKE.

```
SELECT uid FROM {profile_values} 
WHERE value REGEXP '[1][9][8][6-9]|[1][9][9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Well here we make sure that our expression considers only 4 digit number and moreover number should be greater than 1986

```
so [1][9][8][6-9] -->> makes sure number is between 1986 to 1989
next [1][9][9][0-9] -->> makes sure number is between 1990 to 1999
last [2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -->> makes sure number is between 2000 to 9999
```

please refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm for more

Comment: this query does not return records of list of users who born after 1986

Comment: Please check @AbdullaChozhimadathil. Now it should be working.

Comment: Hey Thanks Rockse, Can u also explain the query how u did it, Its gr8.

Comment: Now that needs a thumbs up :P

Comment: @user3572269 check the answer now, it has more explanation now.

Comment: @Rishi : Was this helpful ?